# Как кликнув по карте, получить даные о местоположении в input?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Всем привет!
Есть скрипт из песочницы Яндекс.Карты, [Вот этот](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode)

И есть input, в котором надо вывести название города (а ещё лучше город и адрес) кликнув по карте:

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address">
```

Вопрос: как сделать вывод адреса в инпут при клике на карте.

Comment: В чем именно проблема - в получении адреса или в выводе полученного адреса в нужное поле?

Comment: В выводе. Надо вывести результат в input

Comment: Тогда исправьте заголовок. Он не совпадает с текстом вопроса и вообще не о том, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var  myInput = document.getElementById("address"),
        myPlacemark,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

    // Слушаем клик на карте.
    myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
        var coords = e.get('coords');

        // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
        if (myPlacemark) {
            myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
        }
        // Если нет – создаем.
        else {
            myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
            myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
                getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
            });
        }
        getAddress(coords);
    });

    // Создание метки.
    function createPlacemark(coords) {
        return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            iconCaption: 'поиск...'
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
            draggable: true
        });
    }

    // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
    function getAddress(coords) {
        myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
        ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();

            myPlacemark.properties
                .set({
                    // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                    iconCaption: [
                        // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                        firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                        // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                        firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                    ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                    // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                    balloonContent: address
                });
            myInput.value = address;
        });
    }
}
```

```css
html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 95%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 95%;
        }
        #address {
          width: 80%;
        }
        .header {
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p class="header">Кликните по карте, чтобы узнать адрес</p>
<input type="text" name="address" id="address">
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Андрей, большое спасибо! Проблема решена.

Comment: Ну я смотрю у крутых "знатоков JS на StackOverflow" мнение другое))), а вот самим ответить - религия, наверное, не позволяет ))))